# Zuul forwarding error

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix, netflix-feign

I am facing issues using Zuul and Ribbon. I am using also Eureka for microservice registry.

- I have ribbon-service(port 9000) communicating with the user-service using the REST API
- user-service has 2 instances (on port 8081 and 8091)
- on ribbon-service I have implemented client-side load balancing using hystrix  and feign client
- I consume ribbon-service API using Zuul route, and this API then triggers user-service API

When I start my microservice ecosystem and try to consume ribbon-service API(zuulservice:8761/ribbon-service/) I get the following error:

> com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
>       at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:189) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:164) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:112) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>       at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:117) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
>       at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
>       at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
>       at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:118) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
>       at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
>       at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
>       at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:165) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:44) [spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]................
>   **Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: ribbon-service**
>       at com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext.getServerFromLoadBalancer(LoadBalancerContext.java:483) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
>       at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:184) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
>       at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
>       at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
>       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
>       at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
>       at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]

This error remains for some time, and after that time I get the following output:

> 2018-07-16 12:55:43.260  INFO 19233 --- [erListUpdater-0] c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Flipping property: ribbon-service.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647

After that output everthing works great again.

When I hit eurekaservice:8765/eureka/apps I have registered both ribbon-service and all the user-service instances.

This is my zuul service application.properties:

```
> #Service port
server.port=8765

#Service port
spring.application.name=zuul-service

# Discovery Server Access
 eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone:http://localhost:8761/eureka/
 eureka.instance.lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds=3

 #User service configuration
 zuul.routes.user-service.path:/user-service/**
 zuul.routes.user-service.serviceId:user-service

 #Product service configuration
 zuul.routes.product-service.path:/product-service/**
 zuul.routes.product-service.serviceId:product-service

 #Product service configuration
 zuul.routes.shoppingcart-service.path:/shoppingcart-service/**
 zuul.routes.shoppingcart-service.serviceId:shoppingcart-service

 #Product service configuration
 zuul.routes.payment-service.path:/payment-service/**
 zuul.routes.payment-service.serviceId:payment-service

  #Product service configuration
 zuul.routes.ribbon-service.path:/ribbon-service/**
 zuul.routes.ribbon-service.serviceId:ribbon-service
```

This is my zuul-service bootstrap.properties:

```
> #Application name
spring.application.name=zuul-service

#hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 12600
ribbon.ConnectTimeout: 6000   
ribbon.ReadTimeout: 60000
robbon.eureka.enabled: true

hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled=false
```

I am using spring 2.0.1 and spring cloud Finchley.RELEASE.

Can somebody explain what is going on?

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like Zuul does not yet know about the `ribbon-service`.  Are you starting `ribbon-service` before starting Zuul?  If you are starting it after Zuul it will take some time before Zuul gets the updated information from Eureka.

Comment: It is always started before the zuul service.

Comment: If the `ribbon-service` is started before Zuul and it registers itself before Zuul starts it should be included in the list of services fetched from the Eureka server when Zuul registers itself with Eureka.  I am not sure what else we can do.  Can you provide a sample that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @RyanBaxter thank you for you effort. I start them in correct order, but sometimes this error occurs. Error remains until zuul-service prompt this: INFO 19233 --- [erListUpdater-0] c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty : Flipping property: ribbon-service.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647, cab you explain what is this property for?

Answer (score 0):

The way `DiscoveryClient` works is that it fetches new list of changes from `Eureka` (Service discovery) for every defined time period called `hearbeat`. Until new changes with respect to registered applications propagates from service discovery to your Zuul instance it is bound to have errors.

The output you see in the logs is just the confirmation that it has received this information.

Comment: thank you for you effort. Error remains until zuul-service prompt this: INFO 19233 --- [erListUpdater-0] c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty : Flipping property: ribbon-service.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647, cab you explain what is this property for?

Comment: I would recommend you to go through this section of documenation from Netflix Ribbon. https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon/wiki/Working-with-load-balancers#common-rules.

Comment: **Note**: Here `Discovery client` will supply the list of available servers obtained through service discovery post the `heartbeat` to ribbon configuration. The log you are seeing here is the confirmation that ribbon has accepted the server list based on what was obtained through service discovery.

Comment: Since you are using eureka you can change this heartbeat interval to a minimal amount so that instances are registered quickly for dev / test purpose. It is highly advised not to use this in production environment. See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/373

Comment: you are absolutely right, but I need more concrete answer on this question. Can you please provide more detailed answer in a form of answer, not a comment?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider add strip path config for your zuul configuration.

add stripPrefix=false in every route config